# how to get int values from card game string array

Tags: java

I'm trying a create a card game of war. Each player draws 1 card at a time, up to 26 each. Right now I need to turn the string values of the cards into ints so I can use them to determine who has the higher hand. This is my first program using arrays and I've been having a lot of problems with this program. How would I go about doing this?

**EDIT**: Incase it isn't clear, I'm asking how to get an int value from String [] numbers without manually assigning any values. In order to see who wins each hand I need to compare ints.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Card {
    String finalCard = "";
     int suit, number;
    String [] suits = {"Heart" , "Diamond" , "Spade" , "Club"}; //suits
    String [] numbers = { "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10" , "Jack" , "Queen" , "King" , "Ace" }; //card values
    String card = "";
    public Card() {

    }
     public Card(int suits, int numbers)
        {
            suit = suits; 
            number = numbers;
        }


    public String toString()
        {
            String finalCard = numbers[number] + " of " + suits[suit];
            return finalCard;        
        }
    }

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class FullDeck {
    private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();//card array list

        public FullDeck()
        {   
            for(int a =0; a<=3; a++) //loops through suits
            {
                for(int b =0; b<=12;b++) //loops through values
                {
                    cards.add(new Card(a,b)); //creates adds cards to list
                }

            }

        }

        public Card drawRandomCard()
        {
            Random generator = new Random(); //picks random card
            int index = generator.nextInt(cards.size());
            return cards.remove(index); //removes card from list
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String result = "Cards remaining in deck: " + cards; //not currently used
            return result;
        }    
    }
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WarUI extends JApplet
    implements ActionListener {
        JTextArea displayLabel = new JTextArea(""); //sets label to display message
        JButton runButton = new JButton("Run"); //button that starts program
        Container con = getContentPane(); //gets container


        Card player1;
        Card player2;
        FullDeck hand1 = new FullDeck();

        Card card = new Card();


        public void init() {
            con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//sets flowlayout
            con.add(new JLabel());      //jlabel container
            con.add(runButton);  //run button container
            con.add(displayLabel); //display label container
            runButton.addActionListener(this);//looks to see if run is clicked
           }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                player1= hand1.drawRandomCard(); //draws cards for player 1
                player1.toString();
                }
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                player2= hand1.drawRandomCard(); //draws cards for player 2
                player2.toString(); 
                }

            displayLabel.setText(player1.toString() + "\n" + player2.toString()  ); //displays both players values/suits
                }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the part of the program where you're having problems?

Comment: Have you considered using enums for suit and rank?

Comment: I don't know what an enum is. I just started learning arrays.

Comment: You could also just simplify your design by creating a Card class that has suit, rank and value fields. The value would be your int value that indicates whether one Card object is greater than, less than or equal to another Card object and decouples the value from the human readable suit and rank fields. Implement a comparable interface and write a custom .equals() method and you're on  your way. The only arrays you'd need would be for Deck, which represents undealt cards and Hand, which represents the cards each player holds.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make suits and numbers static in class Card. Because the arrays always keep the same and don't have to be initialized every time you create a card. Although you have to add getters to the variables suit and number in the Card class.

To check which card is higher, you first have to check which numbers index is higher, after that you check for the suits index of a card.

```
Card card1 = ...
Card card2 = ...

if(card1.getnumber() < card2.getnumber())
{
    //card1 is lower
}else if(card1.getnumber() > card2.getnumber()){
    //card2 ist lower
}else{
    if(card1.getsuit() < card2.getsuit()){
        //card1 is lower
    }else if(card1.getsuit() > card2.getsuit()){
        //card2 is lower
    }else{
        // Both Cards are the same
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that with this implementation the order of the suits array is important

Answer (score 0):

To convert the `String` object into primitive `int` just use the `Integer.parseInt()` method as follows:

```
String card1="12";
String card2="20";

int Card1=Integer.parseInt(card1);     
int Card2=Integer.parseInt(card2);

if(Card1>Card2)
{
    System.out.println("You Win!");
}
```